# WebView cocoa doesn't respond to scrollWheel

Tags: cocoa, webview, scrollview

How to make it work? I added the override method in the class inheriting from WebView, but it doesn't get fired.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to subclass a WebView.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

The WebView isn't the one catching the events; from what I remember, it's the frame view's document view that's getting the events, and it's often of class `WebHTMLView`, which is difficult to subclass.

```
[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView]
```

I'm sorry but I don't know what to do to catch a scroll event in that case, maybe method swizzling or something of that sort. (though you can use something like `-enclosingScrollView` and set a custom scroller or something of that type)